# simplifying an expression with even and odd integers

Tags: fourier-series, closed-form

I got this expression for my $b_n$ to a Fourier series:
$$b_n=\frac{(2- \pi^2  n^2)\cos(\pi n) -2}{4( \pi n)^3}$$
Now I want to write it in a closed form without the use of $\text{when } n \text{ is even}$
and $\text{when } n \text{ is odd}$.
How could this be done?

Comment: You mean you want to do more than replace $\cos\pi n$ by $(-1)^n$?

Comment: @almagest Yes, I know this one already.

Comment: Put that is unlikely to be possible. Try looking at the first dozen values. We have $b_n>0$ for $n$ odd and $b_n<0$ for $n$ even.

Answer (score 1):

If n is even then $b_n$ will have the form

> $$ b_{2m}=\frac{(2 -  4\pi^2  m^2)\cos(2\pi m) -2}{4( 2\pi m)^3}= -\frac{  1 }{8\pi m}.$$

I eave it for you to do the odd case. Note that you need  $\cos( (2m+1)\pi ) =(-1)^{m+1}$.